# Powershell Format-Table to CSV

Tags: powershell, csv, formatting

I have the following line in Powershell to output an array of data. The problem I am having is that Name,Title,Department do not go into columns. Instead I get a single column with each row in a single cell with tabs between.

```
$outList | Format-Table Name,Title,Department -auto >c:\Scripts\test2.csv
```

How can I output into columns?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You should be using the Export-Csv cmdlet instead.

```
$outList | Export-Csv -path c:\scripts\test.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

If you need only selected fields, pipe it into a Select-Object cmdlet first.

```
$outList | Select-Object -Property Name, Title, Department | Export-Csv -path c:\scripts\test.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `ConvertTo-Csv` with `select`. Example:

```
$grades | Select Name,Count | ConvertTo-Csv
```