# List files with path and file size only in Command Line

Tags: windows, powershell, command-line, filenames, command-prompt

*Windows Command Line (or maybe PowerShell).*

How can I list all files, recursively, with full path and filesize, but without anything else and export to a .txt file. Much preferably a code that works for whichever current directory I am in with the Command Line (so does not require manual entering of the target directory).

None of these provides path\filename and filesize only:

```
dir /s > filelist.txt
dir /s/b > filelist.txt
dir /s/o:-d > filelist.txt
```

**Desired output (fullpath\file.ext filesize):**

```
c:\aaa\file.ext 7755777    
c:\aaa\bbb\1.txt 897667
c:\aaa\bbb\2.ext 67788990
c:\aaa\bbb\nnn\a.xls 99879000
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | select FullName,Length | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders | Out-File filelist.txt
```

Comment: Awesome! The only cosmetic issue is that the output places an extra blank line between all filenames. Any way to get rid of these blank lines? I am dealing with many TBs and >500K different files.

Comment: even a simple text format with CSV or tab or one blank space separated fields are OK between the path\filename.txt filesize.

Comment: Believe you could just pipe to `convertto-preferredformat`

Comment: one other **functional** issue: if the path or filename is too long, then the path\filename.ext is trimmed and followed by `...` just before the filesize (length) column. for example: `C:\aaa\bbb\ccc\verylongfilena... 99999999`. any possible fix? thank you.

Comment: this works very nicely:
`Get-ChildItem -Recurse | select Length,LastWriteTime,FullName | Format-Table -Wrap -AutoSize | Out-File filelist.txt`
very long path\filename lines are broken into a new line (wrap), but not truncated.

Comment: this does not list the size for me on Win 10

Answer (score 14):

PowerShell:

```
gci -rec -file|%{"$($_.Fullname) $($_.Length)"} >filelist.txt
```

earlier PowerShell versions:

```
gci -rec|?{!$_.PSIsContainer}|%{"$($_.Fullname) $($_.Length)"} >filelist.txt
```

Batch file:

```
(@For /F "Delims=" %%A in ('dir /B/S/A-D') Do @Echo %%~fA %%~zA) >filelist.txt
```

Cmdline

```
(@For /F "Delims=" %A in ('dir /B/S/A-D') Do @Echo %~fA %~zA) >filelist.txt
```

Comment: very nice! `(@For /F "Delims=" %A in ('dir /B/S/A-D') Do @Echo %~fA %~zA) > filelist.txt`

Comment: unfortunately, in CLI, `(@For /F "Delims=" %A in ('dir /B/S/A-D') Do @Echo %~fA %~zA) > filelist.txt` does not perform in **large** subdir trees. tried 1 TB/100K files, kept running for hours until i terminated with ctrl c. still works on small dir trees.

Comment: You might try these two lines `Type nul >filelist.txt` and `@For /F "Delims=" %A ('dir /B/S/A-D ') Do @Echo %~fA %~zA >>filelist.txt`

Comment: in powershell, i get the following error: `Get-ChildItem : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'file'.
At line:1 char:15
+ gci -rec -file <<<<  |%{"$($_.Fullname) $($_.Length)"} > filelist.txt
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ChildItem], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand`

Comment: Looks like you are using an earlier PS version. See changed answer.

Comment: If you want to import this exported txt into something like Excel, separating the filename from the size with a tab (`t) instead of a space will be easier if using the text-to-columns function.

Answer (score 6):

OP's chosen answer using PowerShell (and their comment that they used `Get-ChildItem -Recurse | select Length,LastWriteTime,FullName | Format-Table -Wrap -AutoSize | Out-File filelist.txt`) was almost what I wanted for processing in Excel. Thanks for that part.

Unfortunately, (as they mentioned) the output had wrapped lines for long file paths, which isn't quite what I wanted.

The following command will produce a CSV formatted file (no wrapped lines):

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | select Length,LastWriteTime,FullName | Export-Csv -path filelist.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Kudos to https://stackoverflow.com/a/23434457/7270462 for the tip about `Export-Csv`

Answer (score 3):

```
forfiles /s /c "cmd /c echo @path @fsize" >filelist.txt
```

Comment: This was the only version that worked for me. Maybe it's that I'm visiting from Unixland and my phrasebook is dated?

Answer (score 1):

The following removes the wrapping issue you have:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | select Length,LastWriteTime,FullName | Format-Table -Wrap -AutoSize | out-string -width 4096 | clip
```

Have a look at this [Reference.](https://poshoholic.com/2010/11/11/powershell-quick-tip-creating-wide-tables-with-powershell/)

Answer (score 0):

Go to folder and `shift+Right Click` ---> Powershell and then put in this code.

`gci -rec -file|%{"$($_.Length)~$($_.Name)~$($_.FullName)"} >filelist.txt`

`Ctrl+A` then `Ctrl+C` ---> Copy into Excel

Comment: This is an adjustment of @LotPings comment that worked for me.

Comment: You will need to go to the data tab and use "text to column" --> delimited and instead of separating on "tab" change it to "other" and use "~"