# List of file and the file size using cmd or media info/ffmpeg

Tags: cmd, ffmpeg, command-line, mediainfo

We can use to get the file name `dir /b>list.txt` using windows CMD. is there anyway we can get the file size info with name using cmd/mediainfo/ffmpeg or other app? CMD can generate the file size but it's in "bytes" formate. i am looking for KB/MB/GB format.

```
logo.png 32KB
Header.png 160kb
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe your question already been resolved here you can check directly to this link below.

```
forfiles /s /c "cmd /c echo @path @fsize" >filelist.txt
```

[List files with path and file size only in Command Line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43904684/list-files-with-path-and-file-size-only-in-command-line)

Comment: thank you, is there anyway we can get file size in MB or GB?